# How to get name of file from writeStream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

Here is what I want to do:

```
stream = fs.WriteStream('crap.txt',{flags:'w'};
// more code
response.on('close',function() {
      // is the below line possible?
      fs.stat(stream.name, function(stats) {
            console.log(stats.size);
      });
      stream.end();
});
```

So can I get the filename from the stream object? An illustrated example would be nice, with reference to good tutorial/docs (containing examples) on writable streams.

Comment: Not an answer, but [writeStream.bytesWritten](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#writestreambyteswritten) exists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's `fs.createWriteStream` and `stream.path`

You can `console.dir(stream)` to find all it's properties

Comment: thanks, very to the point and very general! I was unaware of console.dir function, I will use it hence forth for object inspection.

Comment: to tell the truth I just used the repl, with `require('fs').createReadStream('tea.log');` and took a look there.

Comment: currently using windows, don't have good idea how to work with windows command line and open nodejs from there, in linux, I would have done that! I am noob to node though.

Comment: The windows node installer installs a node.js command line just for that purpose.